# How to load table row data from Partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net MVC web application, I'm trying to create a Purchase Order view.

So in this section, I added the table headers that I want to show as the main headers of the form.

```
<table class="proposedWork" width="100%" style="margin-top:20px">
  <thead>
    <th class="docAdd">
      <button type="button" id="addAnotherItm" class="btn btn-info" href="#">+</button>
    </th>
    <th>ITEM</th>
    <th>QTY</th>
    <th>MEASURE BY</th>
    <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
    <th class="amountColumn">TOTAL</th>
  </thead>
```

and then in the body section, I created,

```
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <ul id="PoItmList" style="list-style-type: none"> 
        @if (Model != null && Model.PurchaseOrderItemsViewModelList != null) 
        { 
            foreach (EvoPOS.WebUI.Models.PurchaseOrderItemsViewModel list in Model.PurchaseOrderItemsViewModelList)
            { 
            Html.RenderPartial("_ItemList", list); 
            } 
        } 
        </ul>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

this is the javascript that when the + button is pressed, loads the partial view.

```
$(function () {
  $("#addAnotherItm").click(function () {
    $.get(rootDir + 'PurchaseOrders/AddPoItems', function (template) {
      $("#PoItmList").append(template);
    });
  });
});
```

This is my partial view code,

```
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true"> @Html.DropDownList("Item_ID", null, "Select Items", new { @id = "ddlReqTypes" + Model.TempID, @class = "js-dropdown", @data_map = Model.TempID })</td>
    <td class="unit" contenteditable="true">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td contenteditable="true" class="description">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td class="amount" contenteditable="true">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td class="amount amountColumn rowTotal" contenteditable="true">
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Delete</button>
```

So the view looks like this,

[image]

My issue is When button + is pressed, it should load the dropdown and other inputs with the order of table headers.

But instead of that, happens this,

[image]

I want to load my partial view like this as an example,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To load table row data from a partial view, update your JavaScript code to append the table row directly to the `tbody` element like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#addAnotherItm").click(function () {
    $.get(rootDir + 'PurchaseOrders/AddPoItems', function (template) {
      $("table.proposedWork tbody").append(template);
    });
  });
});
```

And in your partial view, remove the `button` element and place it inside a `td` element:

```html
<tr>
    <!-- other td elements -->
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now, when you click the "+" button, it should load the partial view and append the table row directly to the `tbody` element.

Comment: Hi I tried your code, but still, the same thing happening likewise my picture 2. <td> data loads in the same row where <th> and the headings moves to the right side of the view,